# CSS - setting table column height percentage changes row height

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.patients,
table.patients > tr {
  width: 100%;
}
table.patients td,
table.patients th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table.patients_patient_table tr,
table.patients_patient_table td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.patients_appointment {
  text-align: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.patients_patient {
  text-align: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0px;
}
.patients_patientID {
  text-align: left;
  width: 15%;
}
.patients_sex {
  text-align: left;
  width: 10%;
}
.patients_physician {
  text-align: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.patients_row {
  height: 4em;
}
.patients_patient_table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="patients">
  <tr class="patients_row">
    <td class="patients_appointment">12/20/2014 7:00am</td>
    <td class="patients_patient">
      <table class="patients_patient_table">
        <tr>
          <td>Smith, John</td>
          <td>55 Y</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan=2>test</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="patients_patientID">5678</td>
    <td class="patients_sex">M</td>
    <td class="patients_physician">Dr. John Smith</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The results is the following table:

[image]

If I change the CSS for `.patients_patient` to this:

```
.patients_patient {
    text-align: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.patients,
table.patients > tr {
  width: 100%;
}
table.patients td,
table.patients th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table.patients_patient_table tr,
table.patients_patient_table td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.patients_appointment {
  text-align: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.patients_patient {
  text-align: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
}
.patients_patientID {
  text-align: left;
  width: 15%;
}
.patients_sex {
  text-align: left;
  width: 10%;
}
.patients_physician {
  text-align: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.patients_row {
  height: 4em;
}
.patients_patient_table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="patients">
  <tr class="patients_row">
    <td class="patients_appointment">12/20/2014 7:00am</td>
    <td class="patients_patient">
      <table class="patients_patient_table">
        <tr>
          <td>Smith, John</td>
          <td>55 Y</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan=2>test</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="patients_patientID">5678</td>
    <td class="patients_sex">M</td>
    <td class="patients_physician">Dr. John Smith</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then the height of the outer table row changes:

[image]

Why does this happen?  What I really want is the result to look like this:

[image]

Edit: I am testing this on Chrome.

Comment: On Firefox I get the desired result with both codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code uses

```css
td.patients_patient {
  height: auto; /* default value */
}
td.patients_patient > table.patients_patient_table {
  height: 100%;
}
```

According to [Table height algorithms](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout),

> The height of a table is given by the ['height'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height) property for the
>   'table' or 'inline-table' element.

However, there is a problem, because the [`height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height) is a percentage:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block). If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to 'auto'.

A way to solve that issue is specifying an explicit `height` for `td.patients_patient`, as you did in your second code:

```css
td.patients_patient {
  height: 100%;
}
td.patients_patient > table.patients_patient_table {
  height: 100%;
}
```

However, now there is another problem:

> CSS 2.1 does not define how the height of table cells and table rows
>   is calculated when their height is specified using percentage values.

So you can't use a percentage. But don't worry:

> The height of a 'table-row' element's box is calculated once the user
>   agent has all the cells in the row available: it is the maximum of the
>   row's computed ['height'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height), the computed ['height'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height) of each cell
>   in the row, and the minimum height (MIN) required by the cells.

Therefore, you can use any value not greater than the row's computed `height`, the computed `height` of other cells, and the minimum height required by the cells. Using greater values would also work, but the height of the row would be increased.

For example, you can use

```css
.patients_patient {
    height: 0;
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.patients,
table.patients > tr {
  width: 100%;
}
table.patients td,
table.patients th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table.patients_patient_table tr,
table.patients_patient_table td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.patients_appointment {
  text-align: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.patients_patient {
  text-align: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}
.patients_patientID {
  text-align: left;
  width: 15%;
}
.patients_sex {
  text-align: left;
  width: 10%;
}
.patients_physician {
  text-align: left;
  width: 25%;
}
.patients_row {
  height: 4em;
}
.patients_patient_table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="patients">
  <tr class="patients_row">
    <td class="patients_appointment">12/20/2014 7:00am</td>
    <td class="patients_patient">
      <table class="patients_patient_table">
        <tr>
          <td>Smith, John</td>
          <td>55 Y</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan=2>test</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="patients_patientID">5678</td>
    <td class="patients_sex">M</td>
    <td class="patients_physician">Dr. John Smith</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It does seem to do the trick, but can you please explain why this works and why setting the height to 100% cause the row's height to change?

Comment: @OpenUserX03 Yesterday I didn't have time to add the explanation. I have added it now.