# CSS incorrect height of element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set rows within a table to be 20% of page height.

Currently index.html looks something like this:

```css
div#machines {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  width: 80%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

td {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
}

tr {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="machines">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td id="stone">0</td>
        <td id="copper">0</td>
        <td id="iron">0</td>
        <td id="coal">0</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- ... (trs continue but truncated for length of code) -->
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

So therefore (at least to my understanding) a table is taking up 100% of the machines div then I create a row in that table that is 100% of the width and 20% of the height (but incorrectly the row becomes 100% of the height of the table.) The td should then be 20% of the width of the row and 100% the height of the row.

How can I fix this so that a tr is only 20% of the page height? Thank you.

Comment: Change `#machines` to have `min-height: 100vh`

Comment: I've added `background-color` to the `<td>` elements in order to see them, but is this what you're seeing: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vyt6abfu/?

Comment: @DavidThomas yes, more trs just equally divides the area of the table.

Comment: Very related: [CSS - setting table column height percentage changes row height](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036216/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Viewport units (the browser window size). 100vh is the height of the screen and 100vw is the width of the screen.

If the table higher you can use the min-height property and set it to 100vh.

If i understood the question, i think this css would do what you need:

```
td {width: 20vw;}
tr {height: 20vh;}
table {width: 100%; min-height: 100vh;}
```

Hope it helps.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Answer (score 0):

It's the conflict between the style of your `tr` and `td`. Try removing one each and see the difference. It's not possible to set different heights of the two since `td` is embedded in `tr`.Hope this helps.

Comment: the elements still evenly divide the table once the td's height element has been removed

Comment: try removing the style of tr instead

Comment: You only set width and height in td